# Command line tool for file and registry monitoring

Tags: windows, gratis, command-line, forensics

I would like to capture the files and registry changes etc during application installation through command line. Please help me to get such tools. Actually there are lot of tools available for this purpose and the major tools are not supporting command line options.

If I get the output in a file, It should be fine. The concern is the tool should have cli option to manage while the installer is doing it's job.

Operating System: Windows

Comment: Are you asking to have the changes output to the command line? If so, then you would need to start the install form the command line. there are many, many, many programs to monitor an install, and most of those will let you save the file & registry changes to a text file. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Also, you forgot to tell us which operating system, so pleas add the [tag:Windows] or [tag:linux] or similar tag.  And, please either add the [tag:gratis] tag if it should be free, or state your budget. The more information that you can give us, the more that we can help you.

Comment: I have updated the question with the relevant details. Thanks..

Comment: @Arockia you've missed the price margin :)

Comment: I'm looking for free tools...

Comment: As I suggested previously, I have added the [tag:gratis] tag for you. Please be aware of it in future postings; it will help us to narrow down possible answers for you.